# BeautifulSoup Findall 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import requests

url = "http://chk.tbe.taleo.net/chk01/ats/careers/searchResults.jsp?org=CDI&cws=1"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

table_main = soup.select("table#cws-search-results")

table = table_main.find_all("tr")

for tr in table:
    job_title = tr.find_all("a")
    job_location = tr.find_all("b")

    job = {
         "job_title": job_title,
         "job_location": job_location
    }
    data.append(job)

pprint(jobs)
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It is a pretty obvious error that a simple print could help you figure out.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an error because `soup.select("table#cws-search-results")` is returns a list of `Tag` objects (a 1-item list in this case) rather than a single `Tag` object, and `find_all` is a method of `Tag` objects not of the Python `list` object.

Change:

```
table_main = soup.select("table#cws-search-results")
```

to:

```
table_main = soup.select_one("table#cws-search-results")
```

to get the `Tag` object representing the main table, and then calling `find_all` on that object will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone. But the output seems wrong:
{'job_location': 'Account Executive', 'job_title': 'Account Executive'}
it should be: {'job_location': 'Dallas, TX', 'job_title': 'Account Executive'}
how can I do that?